# Exception not thrown from nested async/await

Tags: c#, exception, async-await, console-application

I have a .NET Core console application.  The exception that occurs within a nested async/await is never thrown:

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var f = new TaskFactory(TaskScheduler.Current);

            await f.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                var x = 0;
                if (x == 0)
                    throw new Exception("we have a problem");

                await Task.Delay(1);
            });
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            // never reaches here
        }
    }
```

If I remove the inner `async`, and drop the call to `await Task.Delay(1)`, the exception is caught.

Comment: Why do you need TaskFactory ?

Comment: the Exception is thrown in anther thread than the main thread that's why it doesn't show up

Comment: In most cases you should use the static method `Task.Run` instead of `TaskFactory.StartNew`. For example it automatically unwraps the inner task in case of an asynchronous delegate, `TaskFactory.StartNew` doesn't.

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada shouldn't awaiting for a task run in the same SynchronizationContext thus propagating the exception? And even that why when OP removes the `await Task.Delay(1);` the exception is thrown?

Comment: That's not part of the function of await?  Shouldn't the first await get the result, and hence encounter any exceptions?

Comment: @dedecos its all on anther thread for testing sake i added a variable"y" 
 var y = 0;
           
                var f = new TaskFactory(TaskScheduler.Current);

                await f.StartNew(async () =>
                {
                    var x = 0;
                    if (x == 0)
                    {
                        y = 99;
                        throw new Exception("we have a problem");                   
                    }
                     
                    await Task.Delay(1);
                });
            Console.WriteLine(y);

Comment: I use a TaskFactory because I want the ability to substitute one TaskScheduler for another.  For example, in a Console app, I might use a synchronous scheduler, but in all other cases the default scheduler.

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada why when removing `await Task.Delay(1);` the exception is propagated then? If the exception is thrown in another thread what is the relation between these two facts?

Comment: @dedecos if you remove await Task.Delay(1); it will not propagate. i tried it 
when u remove aysnc it will. 
its because the became at the same thread

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a classic trap. `TaskFactory` expects a `Func<T>` and returns a `Task<T>`. In your case, `T` is `Task`, therefore you end up with a `Task<Task>` and you need to await both the inner and the outer task. Use `Unwrap` for this:

```
await f.StartNew(async () =>
{
    var x = 0;
    if (x == 0)
        throw new Exception("we have a problem");

    await Task.Delay(1);
}).Unwrap();
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `Task.StartNew` is deprecated function that is super rarely used today as it creates `Task`s that don't work well with `async` `await` and does not understand async delegates. You might want to check Stephen Cleary's article [StartNew is dangerous](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Comment: @Fabjan There's nothing deprecated about `StartNew`, it's still the way to start a task with a custom TaskScheduler or custom flags (such as `LongRunning`). But yes, `Task.Run` is preferred for the most common case

Comment: Honestly, how many times have you used this method in the last two years ?

Comment: @Fabjan I'm a very bad example because I deal with custom task schedulers on a regular basis, so actually quite often :D That said, even without custom task schedulers, using `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` should be a common use-case

Answer (score 2):

Your errors comes from the StartNew.

When you await the StartNew, you expect the job inside to be finished. However, the job you give it is to create a Task. Your StartNew has the following return type `Task<Task>`.
As it is your code ends before the exeception is thrown.

You can solve it by two different ways:

1) you await the result of your start new obtained once the first await has been done

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var f = new TaskFactory(TaskScheduler.Current);

            await await f.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                var x = 0;
                if (x == 0)
                    throw new Exception("we have a problem");

                await Task.Delay(1);
            });
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception received");
            // never reaches here
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
```

2) you stop using StartNew and use the basic task patterns (which I recomend)

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var x = 0;
                if (x == 0)
                    throw new Exception("we have a problem");

                await Task.Delay(1);
            });
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception received");
            // never reaches here
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
```

The reason why removing `Task.Delay(1)` solve your issue is because you change the signature of your StartNew to Task instead of `Task<Task>` which makes your single await efficient

Comment: `Task.Run` won't do if OP wants to use a different task scheduler

Comment: Yes I wrote this before he specified that. Anyway I also provided a solution with his own way of doing.